# JMeter - Can I know current row number(s) of CSV Data Set Config?

Tags: jmeter

I'm executing JMeter with Infinite loop test driven from CSV Data Set Config

Which stop when ends:

- Recycle on EOF false
- Stop Thread on EOF true

I want to know the remaining time of execution dynamically by CSV records number,

For example 1000 rows, each takes seconds - 1000 seconds

And if it's not possible, at least to print row number in similar way of printing `${__threadNum}`

Is there such option(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the exact solution you are looking out for but still, let me put it down here. The easiest solution that can work out for you, if you are going to run a single user execution, then you can use `getIteration()` [method](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration--). This way, you can use [JSR223 element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and print current iteration number which would also be your row number.

But this won't work if you are going to perform an execution with the multiple users/threads. What I suggest is - ***please add one more extra field[column] in csv for row number*** and add numbering from 1,2...., n to the rows of the data you have in csv. Now that you can create/use the variable for newly added 'rowNumber' column, you can use it anywhere in the script as per your need, to print out to find out where the execution is at any given time.

Hope this helps.